# How to discover if an Ext.FormPanel is changed

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, formpanel

i've some Ext.FormPanel and i want to enable the "Save" button only when the user changes the values inside the form. How can i discover that the user changed some fields ?

I've tried with form.on("change"), SelectionMode but without any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply check

```
var myFormPanel = // get a reference to the form panel
if (myFormPanel.getForm().isDirty()) {
    // submit your form
}
```

in your `click`-handler on the "Save"-button.

Comment: Huge thanks! i known that Ext had some elegant solution for this! I've founded that i have to set trackResetOnLoad:true on the form to make it works correctly - Thanks again